# Can't launch browser through RStudio's taskscheduler

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rstudio

I'm trying to crawl data from a website using RSelenium. The scrip below runs perfectly in RStudio

## Code

```
library(RSelenium)   
library(rvest)    
library(xlsx)    
library(XML)    
library(RODBC)    
library(taskscheduleR)    
library(DBI)    
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};server=HG-SOS-MI;database=Data_Testing;trusted_connection=yes")
driver<- rsDriver()    
browser <- driver[["client"]]    
browser$navigate("www.goal.com/en-us")    
browser$maxWindowSize()
```

## Error Log

But when I schedule it using the built-in taskScheduleR, I get the following in the error log:

```
Loading required package: methods
Warning message:
package 'DBI' was built under R version 3.4.4 
Loading required package: xml2
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
Warning messages:
1: package 'xlsx' was built under R version 3.4.3 
2: package 'rJava' was built under R version 3.4.3 

Attaching package: 'XML'

The following object is masked from 'package:rvest':

xml

Warning message:
package 'taskscheduleR' was built under R version 3.4.3 
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD

Error in subprocess::spawn_process(tfile, ...) : 
  could not create process: Access is denied
Calls: rsDriver ... spawn_tofile -> windows_spawn_tofile -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

## sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] subprocess_0.8.2  odbc_1.1.6        shiny_1.1.0       taskscheduleR_1.1 RODBC_1.3-15     
 [6] stringr_1.3.1     rlist_0.4.6.1     plyr_1.8.4        rvest_0.3.2       xml2_1.2.0       
[11] RSelenium_1.7.1   XML_4.0-0         RPostgreSQL_0.6-2 DBI_1.0.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] promises_1.0.1    bitops_1.0-6      bit_1.1-14        pkgconfig_2.0.1   blob_1.1.1       
 [6] compiler_3.5.0    xtable_1.8-2      wdman_0.2.2       Rcpp_0.12.17      httr_1.3.1       
[11] tools_3.5.0       openssl_1.0.1     R6_2.2.2          semver_0.2.0      assertthat_0.2.0 
[16] curl_3.2          digest_0.6.15     mime_0.5          miniUI_0.1.1.1    stringi_1.1.7    
[21] caTools_1.17.1    htmltools_0.3.6   hms_0.4.2         bit64_0.9-7       data.table_1.11.4
[26] httpuv_1.4.4.1    binman_0.1.0      rlang_0.2.1       magrittr_1.5      rappdirs_0.3.1   
[31] yaml_2.1.19       later_0.7.3       jsonlite_1.5
```

## error in docker

```
> rD <- rsDriver()

checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD

[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Comment: which version of do you have?

Comment: @Mislav I use R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)

Comment: than you have to upgrade, best to 3.5

Comment: @Mislav I've upgrade to R version 3.5.0 and RStudio Version 1.1.453. However, the error in the log is still the same.

Comment: can you provide output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Mislav I've added the output in the question as requested

Comment: It is recommended to run RSelenium through Docker or using wdman package. Have you tryed these?

Comment: I've tried docker and I'm getting the error I posted above. I think it has to do with the chromedriver but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: can you try `chrome_driver <- wdman::chrome()
driver <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567L)
driver$open()`

Comment: chrome_driver <- wdman::chrome() 
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> driver <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567L) 
> driver$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs x86_64)

Comment: I'm also thinking, maybe it can't locate the chromedriver path. Maybe I need to specify this. I'm new to docker. Struggling to locate the directories

Comment: Have you added chrome driver to environment path?

Comment: rstudio@f7953541190a:~$ ls /home/rstudio/bin
chromedriver  chromedriver.exe  phantomjs
I've added this to my working directory and also the "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin" but error still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also experience that problem and solve that problem with "window task scheduler".

1.First, create schedule using taskscheduler_create function.

```
Jobplanet <- "Directory where your R script located."
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "R03_Jobpnanet_Review_Crawling", rscript = Jobplanet, 
                 schedule = "MONTHLY", starttime = "17:20", startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y/%m/%d"),
                 days = 31)
```

2.And then, open the window task scheduler and double click the created task.
[image]

3.Check "Run whether user is logged on or not" and change "Configure for" option as "Windows7, Windows Server 2008 R2" [image]

Please try. It works well to me.